# ActionScript - Accessing TextField Context Menu Events?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, contextmenu, textfield

TextField objects have a built in context menu containing items which target cut, copy, paste, delete and select all events.

i would like to map keyboard keys and modifiers to these events to obtain their free functionality.

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the documentation (InteractiveObject Class):

> TextField objects do not dispatch
>   clear, copy, cut, paste, or selectAll
>   events. TextField objects always
>   include Cut, Copy, Paste, Clear, and
>   Select All commands in the context
>   menu. You cannot remove these commands
>   from the context menu for TextField
>   objects. For TextField objects,
>   selecting these commands (or their
>   keyboard equivalents) does not
>   generate clear, copy, cut, paste, or
>   selectAll events. However, other
>   classes that extend the
>   InteractiveObject class, including
>   components built using the Flash Text
>   Engine (FTE), can dispatch these
>   events.

in AIR, it's mind-numbingly simple to accomplish this, as they are built-in public methods of the NativeApplication class.

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.cut();        //Cut
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.copy();       //Copy
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.paste();      //Paste
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.clear();      //Delete
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.selectAll();  //Select All
```